# Button to delete multiple row from multiple table based on id

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a button to delete multiple row from multiple table based on id

this is my controller:

```
    function deletesiswa()
{
    $delete = $this->input->post('delete', TRUE);
    $query = $this->db->query("DELETE pengguna, tb_datadiri, tb_nilai, tb_orangtua, tb_prestasi
    FROM pengguna
    INNER JOIN tb_datadiri ON tb_datadiri.id = pengguna.id
    INNER JOIN tb_nilai ON tb_nilai.id = pengguna.id
    INNER JOIN tb_orangtua ON tb_orangtua.id = pengguna.id
    INNER JOIN tb_prestasi ON tb_prestasi.id = pengguna.id
    WHERE pengguna.id = $delete");
    return $data->result();
    redirect('admin/datasiswa');
}
```

this is my view:

```
<a href="<?php anchor('crud_controller/deletesiswa/' . $siswa->id); ?>"> <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn" style="background-color: #FF4D4D; color: white; font-size:10px;">delete</button></a>
```

When I click the button it doesn't delete the data row based on id. what I'm missing here?

Comment: Does it work in your query tool?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, but i change the $data->result(); with specific id number? im confused with that where condition